# Saving rows into variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, storing-data

I have a 18-by-48 matrix. 
Is there a way to save each of the 18 rows automatically in a separate variable (e.g., from r1 to r18) ?

Comment: Any example data ?

Comment: why would you want to do that? That will clutter your namespace/environment with too many variables. You can index the matrix with the integers 1 through 18. You could even put each row inside a `list` and have the `names` of the list be `sprintf("r%s", 1:18)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely advise against splitting a `data.frame` or `matrix` into its constituent rows. If i absolutely had to split the rows up, I'd put them in a `list` then operate from there.

If you desperately had to split it up, you could do something like this:

```
toy <- matrix(1:(18*48),18,48)

variables <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(toy)){
  variables[[paste0("variable", i)]] <- toy[i,]
}

list2env(variables, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

I'd be inclined to stop after the for loop and avoid the `list2env`. But I think this should give you your result.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can select a row r from your dataframe d by indexing without a column specified:

```
var <- d[r,]
```

Thus you can extract all of the rows into a variable by using

```
var <- d[1:length(d),]
```

Where var[1] is the first row, var[2] the second. Etc.. not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for. Why would you want 18 different variables for each row?

Comment: this is a good answer, but I want the computer does it for me at one go instead of doing it 18 times

Answer (score 0):

```
result <- data.frame(t(mat))
colnames(result) <- paste("r", 1:18, sep="")
attach(result)
```

your matrix is `mat`

Comment: The following objects are masked from result (pos = 3):

    r1, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, r15, r16, r17, r18, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9

Comment: `attach` is one of the worst things about R. It should never be used.